# Beamer - How to insert miscellaneous slides between a sequence of bullet points

Tags: beamer, transparency

I'm trying to uncover bullet points in the following way.  On the first slide, display bullet point 1 in regular text and bullet point 2 grayed out (future material).  Then have miscellaneous slides appear.  Finally, have a slide with bullet point 1 grayed out (past material) and bullet point 2 in regular text.

A previous post gave a solution to a similar problem, except that I want bullet point 1 greyed out on the last slide.  Below is close to what I want using the strategy of the previous post

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 

\begin{frame} <1>  [label=blub]
\begin{enumerate}
\item Point 1
\begin{itemize}
\item More info about point 1
\end{itemize}
\pause
\item Point 2
\begin{itemize}
\item More info about point 2
\end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2> {blub} 

\end{document}
```

I'm quite new to Beamer so I imagine the solution may be very simple

Comment: This *not* a duplicate. The OP is not asking for how to "list transparency across non consecutive slides", he has made that clear in the post, rather nicely. He wanted to know how to dim the second point in the first slide, insert an explanation slide, and then insert the first slide with the first pointed dimmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply tell the points when to appear.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} 

\begin{frame} <1>  [label=blub]
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item <1> Point 1
    \begin{itemize}
    \item More info about point 1
    \end{itemize}
  \item <2> Point 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item More info about point 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item miscellaneous
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2> {blub} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @sean123 Glad to be of assistance. Now you can upvote and accept my answer :-)

Comment: When I upvoted it, it says that I don't have enough reputation points for my feedback to be publicly displayed (since I just joined).  It appears that it allowed me to accept your answer though

Comment: I can live with those 15 points now, and sleep on the dream that you will be able to upvote some day very soon. :-)